# How to pass an uninitialized PDA account to a CPI to initialize it without getting AccountNotInitialized error

Tags: solana-program, pda, account, cpi, initialize

I have *ProgramA* and *ProgramB*. *ProgramA* initializes an account using *InstructionA*. When *ProgramB* uses a CPI to call *instructionA* I'm getting `AccountNotInitialized` error.

I'm using the following code:

*ProgramA*:

```
pub fn initialize(_ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
    Ok(())
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [PDA_SEED.as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = authority,
        space = 16 + 8
    )]
    pub account_a: Account<'info, AccountA>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

*ProgramB*:

```
pub fn call_program_a(_ctx: Context<CallProgramA>) -> Result<()> {
    let cpi_program = self.program_a.to_account_info();
    let cpi_accounts = Initialize {
        authority: self.authority.to_account_info(),
        account_a: self.account_a.to_account_info(),
        system_program: self.system_program.to_account_info(),
        };
        CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts)
    Ok(())
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CallProgramA<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub account_a: Account<'info, AccountA>,
    pub program_a: Program<'info, ProgramA>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Client side:

```
const [pdaAccountA, _bump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
    [Buffer.from(PDA_SEED)],
     ProgramA.programId
);

await ProgramA.rpc.callProgramA(
    {
        accounts: {
            authority: authority,
            accountA: pdaAccountA,
            programA: ProgramA,
            systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
        },
        signers: []
    }
);
```

The `AccountNotInitialized` error arises when making the CPI call, since `accountA` has to be initialized and this is not possible since it is initialized when making the CPI call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using program B to initialize a PDA derived from program A's address, try passing in the address of `account_a` into program B as an unchecked account.

The address you provide as `account_a` will be checked in the `Initialize` struct of program A through the CPI.

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CallProgramA<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    /// CHECK: PDA checked in program A
    #[account(mut)]
    pub account_a: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    pub program_a: Program<'info, ProgramA>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

If you wanted to validate the PDA in program B, one approach is to include a check within the instruction and return a custom Anchor Error if the provided PDA is not the expected address.

```
   pub fn call_program_a(_ctx: Context<CallProgramA>) -> Result<()> {
        let (pda, _bump_seed) =
            Pubkey::find_program_address(&[PDA_SEED.as_ref()], &ctx.accounts.program_a.key());

        if pda != ctx.accounts.account_a.key() {
            return err!(ErrorCode::IncorrectPDA);
        }

        ...
        Ok(())
    }
```

You can implement a custom Anchor Error like this:

```
#[error_code]
pub enum ErrorCode {
    #[msg("Incorrect PDA")]
    IncorrectPDA,
}
```

If the PDA is incorrect, then program B would return something like this:

```
Error Code: IncorrectPDA. Error Number: 6000. Error Message: Incorrect PDA.
```

Comment: I have set `pub account_a: UncheckedAccount<'info>` and I get the following errors: `Transfer: \`from\` must not carry data` `failed: invalid program argument`. I have also made sure that the PDA sent from the client (`pdaAccountA`) is the correct one. I think this solution is closer to the correct one.

Comment: Is there more to your program than what's provided in the question? Not sure what would be causing that error. Here is a reference where I tried to initializing a pda via a cpi using Anchor 0.25.0, https://github.com/ZYJLiu/cpi-init

Comment: This example has been very useful. The last error was caused by the use of `.with_signer` in the cpi call from `ProgramB` (this is not shown in the question because I tried to simplify it). I have copied your code and now everything works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

ProgramB expects `account_a` to be initialized.

**In ProgramB**,
This code checks if `account_a` is initialized and checks the account discriminator to make sure that's the expected structure.

```
    #[account(mut)]
    pub account_a: Account<'info, AccountA>,
```

Change it to

```
    #[account(
        seeds = [PDA_SEED.as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub account_a: SystemAccount<'info>
```

Comment: With your solution I'm getting: `The given account is not owned by the system program`   
I also tried:  
`#[account( seeds = [PDA_SEED.as_ref()], bump, )] pub account_a: Account<'info, AccountA>,` getting the error: `A seeds constraint was violated`

Comment: does changing `SystemAccount<'info>` to `AccountInfo<'info>` work?

Comment: I don't think you would be able to use `#[account( seeds = [PDA_SEED.as_ref()], bump, )]` in program B in this example since it would derive the PDA using the address of program B instead of program A.

Comment: using `AccountInfo<'info>` along with `#[account( seeds = [PDA_SEED.as_ref()], bump, )]` I get the same error, I think that @Hi_I'mJohn is right as it explains the error `A seeds constraint was violated` error

Comment: Considering that the seeds are correct, You have to pass it as a SystemAccount or AccountInfo in programB